# Device not receiving the Push Notification

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have created one iPhone application. I am getting Device Token. But I am not able to receive notification from APNS. Here I have given the sample code for server in PHP.

I got the code (PHP) from below url:

http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/

### APNS.php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
require_once 'ApnsPHP/Autoload.php';
$push = new ApnsPHP_Push(
ApnsPHP_Abstract::ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX,
'ApnsPHP/apple_push_notification_production.pem'
);

$push->setRootCertificationAuthority('ApnsPHP/entrust_root_certification_authority.pem');
$push->connect();
$message = new ApnsPHP_Message('****');
$message->setCustomIdentifier("Message-Badge-5");
$message->setText('Hello APNs-enabled device!');
$message->setBadge(5);
$message->setSound('default');
$message->setCustomProperty('acme2', array('bang', 'whiz'));
$message->setExpiry(30);
$push->add($message);
$push->send();
$push->disconnect();
$aErrorQueue = $push->getErrors();
if (!empty($aErrorQueue)) {
var_dump($aErrorQueue);
}
```

### Objective C:

```
-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application{
    NSLog(@"Initiating push notification.");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{
    NSLog(@"Device Token : %@", deviceToken);
    self.currentDeviceToken = [[[deviceToken description] 
                                                      stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@""]] 
                                                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];;
    NSLog(@"Device Token : %@", self.currentDeviceToken);
    NSLog(@"Remote type : %d", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]);
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Error in registration : %@", error);
    self.currentDeviceToken = @"no device token";
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSLog(@"Received Notification");
    NSLog(@"remote notification: %@",[userInfo description]);
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

    NSString *alert = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Alert: %@", alert);

    NSString *sound = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"sound"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Sound: %@", sound);

    NSString *badge = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Badge: %@", badge);
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];
}
```

Please help me resolve this issues.

Thanks.

Comment: When I run the server, I am getting below message. I think it is working fine. "Mon, 11 Oct 2010 18:59:38 +0530 ApnsPHP[7616]: INFO: Sending messages queue, run #1: 1 message(s) left in queue.
Mon, 11 Oct 2010 18:59:38 +0530 ApnsPHP[7616]: STATUS: Sending message ID 1 [custom identifier: Message-Badge-5]: 151 bytes.
"

Comment: From the server it is sending the notification to APNS. But iPhone application did not receiving that notification. Please any one help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue.

I have created entitlements.plist for my application. Now it is working fine.